# PHP Symfony Router Error

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm a newbie at Symfony and working on it Symfony documentations. At the lucky number sample(https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)

My luckycontroller.php is:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php

namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

in my routes.yaml file:

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

I've looked for routes on the console:

[image]

it shows app_lucky_number route

Then I'm going http://127.0.0.1/projects/todolist/public/lucky/number it gives 404 error.

I didn't understand what did I do wrong. I installed Symfony by using composer.

Comment: have you set your working directory in your apache config to /public? If so you just need to navigate to: http://127.0.0.1/lucky/number

Comment: I didn't install Symfony to the whole server. I've just installed it  C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/todolist/ Is it wrong?

Comment: have you got any view currently working? A sample page of any kind?

Comment: Probably missing the htaccess file.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules But for development, you can install the test server though the answer below is missing a fairly key step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html:

> Before continuing, make sure you've read the [Setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) article and can
>   access your new Symfony app in the browser.

To quickly test Symfony without configuring Apache you can go to your project directory and run this in your terminal:

```
php bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000
```

then you should be able to access your new controller using this URI http://localhost:8000/lucky/number

To configure Apache server use this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Ok I handled it. It's about symfony installation folder. I installed it to  C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/todolist instead of C:/xampp/htdocs. Thank you.